# Extension board for network router building

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless

I am looking to build my own network router (with hardware assembly not hardware design...) and I want to know if I can find some extension card for the raspberry pi dedicated to networking.

The idea will be to build a network router that has the following features

- Gigabit wire ports (3 or 4)
- 802.11ac support
- Dual band (if possible)
- support openWrt (or other OS dedicated to network administration).

I know that the USB/RJ45 port of the Raspberry Pi can be very slow (and are not sufficient for 802.11ac). That's why I am looking for a dedicated extension card (with maybe a specific chipset for managing the network...).

Comment: What is the point of the Raspberry Pi?  Even if you could find such a card, why?

Comment: One answer: why not? More seriously I have one raspberry pi that I don't use currently and I have a very bad quality router.... (very very very bad :-)). And also I want to try it for fun ;-)

Comment: I was wondering about the chances of such a card existing.  If there was a compelling reason for the card it's more likely that one has been built.  The developers would need to recover their costs.  If there are few potential buyers (1?) it will be expensive if it exists at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such hardware for the raspberry pi. The Pi is simply too slow to handle that kind of speeds, and while it would be possible to offload the pi with a specific chip set, as you yourself point out, that would make the pi superfluous in the device and there would be no point in having it at all.